# Report issues about a header file in /opt/ros/kinetic/include

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently found an issue in a file in /opt/ros/kinetic/include. Which issue tracker should I report the issue?

[Edit] Here is the issue

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/serialization.h:234:5: runtime error: store to misaligned address 0x60600000aca4 for type 'double', which requires 8 byte alignment
0x60600000aca4: note: pointer points here
  30 00 00 00 be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be be be be be
              ^
```

The issue is detected when I am using Ubsan with turtlesim. Ubsan is a sanitizer for detecting undefined behavior. Many times misalignment is only a minor issue. But I am not sure if it is the case here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309507/report-issues-about-a-header-file-in-/opt/ros/kinetic/include./) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-27**:
Have a look at https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-11-27**:
@zell which include file is the issue? It would be helpful to see the output of `dpkg -S /opt/ros/kinetic/include/[specific file]`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-27**:
In addition to what @allenh1 writes, it would also be nice to know what the actual issue is.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-11-27**:
@gvdhoorn See my update above.

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-11-27**:
@allenh1 With your suggested "dpkg -S ..." command, I got "ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/serialization.h".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> @allenh1 With your suggested `dpkg -S ...` command, I got `ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/serialization.h`.

In that case, the correct repo is here: https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core

If you know how to fix it, I'd encourage a PR instead of an issue!

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2018-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1